# How to know if an API response has changed?

Tags: http, request, response

I'm working with a REST API which is returning the data I want as a JSON response. Effectively, I want to only process new data that hasn't been processed before, but I'm struggling to know the best way to go about this.

One idea I had was to hash the whole JSON response and store it in a variable, then every time I poll the API for new data, I hash it and check it against the hash of the previous call, then if the hash is different I know the data is different. Obviously, this seems like a very inefficient way to know if there is new data, and was wondering how I can do this better.

I'm using the request npm module.

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can try to do is to implement a set of HTTP headers by yourself. The headers you are looking for are:

- ETag
- If-Modified-Since
- If-Unmodifed-Since
- If-Modified
- If-Match

You'll find basic characteristics of the mentioned headers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).
For the purpose of your application it seems that `ETag` will be the best. Every response from the server should have `ETag` header. Next time when the same set of data is requested `ETag` should be included in request. Server decides if data has changed since the last call (based on `ETag`). If so, 200 is returned along with the new set, otherwise `304`.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of data I tried searching the http response for, but to no avail. Implementing them by myself is a suboptimal solution, but there's probably an npm package out there that can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: All the headers are returned from server, remember that. If my answer helped you, please accept it.